# why is it important for the random component in the time series model to be white noise?

Tags: time-series, white-noise

I am curious to know why is it important to ensure that the random component in the time series model is white noise? what is the significance behind it? Also, if the random component is white noise, then should we be concerned with MA component or can we directly model the data?

Comment: It's analogous to the error component in a linear model. Whatever is left (that is not explained by the model) is due only to chance, that which cannot be explained.

Comment: If it's not white noise, what will it be?  You need an *explicit,* *quantitative* model if you wish to be able to analyze it theoretically.  In many cases, anything more complicated than white noise would be made an explicit part of your model.  Your questions about "concerned with MA component" and "directly model" are so vague that it's difficult to see how objective answers could be offered.  Could you explain what you mean by them?